# Rename tag "Naruto" to "Naruto-Shippuuden"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I want to ask question about Naruto (the 2005 version).
And I think that if I say something like "what happened in the 10 episode?" it may cause some misunderstandings.

Comment: would synonym tag suffice?

Comment: Can't you just say in the question title/body? [tag:naruto] should refer to everything in the Naruto-franchise, including both anime series, IMO.

Comment: why? it's like total different series...

Comment: As far as I know, the manga didn't change names, so it's still the same series. More importantly, it cuts down on the number of tags. If we allowed a shippuuden tag, we'd also have to start adding fma-brotherhood, clannad-after-story, etc. I don't see what it adds except one more tag for everyone to favorite/ignore.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do?
Treat it like it's the same anime and every time to re-emphasize if it belongs to the old or the new series?

Comment: If you think it's likely that people will misunderstand, in your question title or body, use something like "In episode 10 of Naruto (original series), ..."

Comment: I do not think it's such a good idea.

Comment: Also it's like "Dragonball" it isn't "Dragonball-z" etc.

Comment: Like @LoganM said in the manga Naruto and Naruto:Shippuden ARE just one whole series. No name changed. When you ask a question you could just put, "In episode XX of Naruto:Shippuden (or just Naruto if it's just in the first series) this happened. If you put Naruto or Naruto:Shippuden it shouldn't confuse anyone, or you could just be referring to the whole series. Which is okay. I mean when I ask questions about Naruto it's normally from the manga, and it hasn't confused anyone yet.

Comment: [status-declined], because I came from Blend S and not Naruto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If you ask **"In episode XX of Naruto........"**, it means the first series.
- If you ask **"In episode XX of Naruto Shippuuden........"**, it means the Shippuuden series.

I do not think there is any need to create tags specific to each one of them.

Comment: that's a good pointt. /=