# Should we have separate tags for the Dragon Ball series?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, lumping-and-splitting

It was pointed out in comments at [Rename tag "Naruto" to "Naruto-Shippuuden"](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/rename-tag-naruto-to-naruto-shippuuden) that we have separate tags for [dragonball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-z) and [dragonball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-gt), and we'll probably end up with a [dragonball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball) eventually. However, in the case of Naruto, one tag [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) is encompassing the whole series. (Also, Dragon Ball has a space in it, which was not included in the tags for whatever reason.)

This is inconsistent, since Dragon Ball was a single manga from which both the Dragon Ball and Dragon Ball Z anime were made (at least in Japan; in English-speaking countries). It would seem that we should use [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball) for all of these questions, with [dragon-ball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z) as a synonym. GT is a bit strange, but at least based on my logic for the linked question, being part of the same franchise and story, it should also be included in [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball).

However, even though this is consistent, I get the feeling that new users will have trouble with it. In principle making the synonym should fix things. However, I get the feeling that people will have trouble with it.

Should we keep it separated (thereby using a different convention from Naruto and some other series) or should we move all of these to [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball) and make [dragon-ball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z) and [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt) synonyms? Either way, we should probably switch "dragonball" to "dragon ball" in all of the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say we only use [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball).

As you mentioned with Naturo, we also only use [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto), especially because Naruto Shippuuden is a continuation of the original story.

It is the same with Dragon Ball and Dragon Ball Z. It is a continuation and it does not matter about which series the question is as the question itself needs to make clear what it is about. (and people automatically know which series it is).

Only thing is Dragon Ball GT. I did not watch it (and not planning to), so I do not know whether the story is clashing with Dragon Ball and Dragon Ball Z. If so, we could give it it's separate tag.

But, I think it is better to given them all the [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball). As said for many other tags/discussions, the question will make clear what it is about.

*Additional note*: I would say that we use this reasoning for all tags from now on, otherwise we keep on discussing the same things over and over.

Comment: [tag:dragon-ball-gt] should be given a separate tag, since it's a completely different and independent work from he manga.