# Are the Dragonball tags inconsistent?

Tags: discussion, retagging, lumping-and-splitting

As they are now, the Dragonball tags are

- [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball) == [dragonball-z](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-z)
- [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt)

DB being a synonym for DBZ feels rather inconsistent because DB and DBZ are completely different parts of the DB story. So it might be that some readers/viewers don't know about this and refer to DBZ as just DB as it's global name (and this was probably the reason why they became a synonym?), but then why isn't DB-GT a synonym of DB too? Since this too would then be part of the DB franchise, wouldn't it?

I just noticed that there was a previous discussion about this [Should we have separate tags for the Dragon Ball series?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-dragon-ball-series). Here it seems that the conclusion was indeed to either drop both DBZ and DBGT or make DB a synonym for both. Was there a reason this didn't happen or did people just forget about it?

Comment: Did you notice [this comment](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-dragon-ball-series#comment439_215) in the post you linked?

Comment: @キルア I did, but didn't give it much thought. I just verified and it was indeed independent. I never knew DBGT wasn't based on any manga either. Coming from the anime, it just looked as if there were three parts in the story. Well then I guess in a way it makes sense not to have them as synonyms.

Comment: It's true that the Dragon Ball manga covers Dragon Ball and DBZ but not GT, and that's why we have a separate tag for GT. However, to what degree that's actually needed and useful is a different story. I think a good argument could be made for merging them.

Comment: What about Dragon Ball Kai? Does that share the dragon-ball tag?

Comment: @LoganM To be honest if I'd like to browse through all dragonball questions I would expect DBZ questions to be included aswell as DBGT questions. Not sure how Kai fits in this but I would expect DB-kai == DB. Also would the synonyms be transitive? I mean if DB==DBZ and DB==DBGT would that mean if you search for DBZ questions you would also find DBGT questions? Or wouldnt you, because those are not explicitely made synonyms? If its the former I'd vote for merge. if its the latter I'd only vote for them to be synonyms regardless of the independence. Movies are independent too but still included.