# Should we merge the dragon-ball and dragon-ball-gt tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

Looking at [Should we have separate tags for the Dragon Ball series?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-we-have-separate-tags-for-the-dragon-ball-series), it would seem that there was an overall consensus about the [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball) tag being the canonical tag for all of the dragonball franchise.

I also noticed that we have [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt) which is a separate tag with 12 questions.

Do we want the two merged, as per the consensus from 2012? Keep them separate?